# Asp.Net PageLoading takes toomuch times

Tags: asp.net

In my application search option is there it took time to search almost 60 seconds i just want to do search function just like a make my trip searching feature

Comment: which database are you using

Comment: with out knowing the technology you are using, i cant say much, but simply i can say, when a search is done and there should not be branching,for obtaining count or anything, only one procedrue and one query  at a time  should run in any case, want to see more of your code

Comment: @need search function like this if suppose user searched something then according to the searched we have 10 items found, Normally every one does like this if i got whole searched results found then they will display the searched result but i want like this if user searched something according to search we got 10 results and i want i like this if i got 1 result is should display the searched result to the users and remaining 9 result should bind the result on page load this kind of result i want just go and visit make my trip search function and help me to implement this function in my project

Comment: @ Arun Asp.Net ,Sql Server

Answer (score 0):

At this point only thing i can do is recommend few technologies to achieve this

Sql Server -> Full Text Specification, Search with Contains, 'case when then' in query, stored procedure, limit the results for paging using 'Offset 10 Fetch next 10' method, Grouping to generate the total result count with in the query, @@Rowcount to get he total number of results .. i dont know if this help